# Communicate with Telegram - iOS 8 (In-App Communication)

Tags: objective-c, ios8, url-scheme

I would like to make sure that I can't communicate with `Telegram` on `iOS 8`. My goal would be open Telegram from my app after touching an `UIButton`, passing my phone number in this process as parameter being it the sender, and that Telegram could handle a new text messaging to some particular phone number.

If Telegram doesn't has an own custom '`URL Scheme`', I can't do that, right? Even on iOS 8.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The iOS Telegram version 2.8 supports URL Schema **tg** and **telegram** with this parameters:

- //msg?

  - to
  - text
- //download-language?
- //resolve?

**Example** for sending a message with the text "Foo" to +391234567 :

```
tg://msg?text=Foo&to=+393331234657
```

More info in the official doc:
[Telegram URI Scheme](http://telegram.wiki/general/urischeme?s%5b%5d=uri); you can also see the implementation in the [TGAppDelegate.mm](https://github.com/peter-iakovlev/Telegram/blob/public/Telegraph/TGAppDelegate.mm) class

Comment: Where I can find more info about the `resolve` parameter?

Comment: @GiulianoIacobelli I've updated the answer with the link to the class that implement the URL handling

Comment: The link to telegram wiki is changed to [this](http://telegram.wiki/general/urischeme?s%5b%5d=uri).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you answered your own question. Unless Telegram offers a custom URL scheme ([which it promised to do in *the future*](https://twitter.com/telegram/status/448441021320265728), but [didn't do until the time of writing](http://handleopenurl.com/search?scheme=telegram)), you are not able to accomplish your task.